# Turn dplyr pipeline into function

Tags: r, dplyr

The code below works on my sample data for the single value of 50 but I am having trouble creating a way to parameterize the results by the click.amount variable, specifically the range 20:200. The variable definitions are:

- date= timestamp of event
- ID=uniquely determines the user
- Group= a grouping variable
- click= clicks per event(always =1)
- click.amount=amount spent during event
- Correct.Outcome=what my code should return
- Reason =The reason why an outcome would be "N"

The criteria for an event to have outcome="Y"

1. click amount <=N
2. cumulative clicks By ID <=5
3. cumulative amount By ID<=N
4. Group=A

For the sample code N=50, ultimately I would like to return a data frame where the rows represent proportion of  Outcome="Y" and total click.amount for Outcome="Y" for each click.amount in the range 20:200. My actual data is around 500K to a 1M rows. If a cleaner solution exist without using dplyr that is fine, the code below just represents how I was able to get a partial solution. TIA

data:

```
    structure(list(date = c(1550245200, 1550245211, 1550245411, 1552566300, 
1552566350, 1552567300, 1552567400, 1552567500, 1552568600, 1552568600, 
1552568601, 1552568691, 1552568691, 1552568891, 1552568899, 1552568601, 
1552568691, 1552568691, 1552568891, 1552568899), ID = c(1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8), Group = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), clicks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), click.amount = c(60, 
4.89, 12.84, 70, 52, 10, 33, 80, 54, 11.89, 15.24, 25, 2, 1, 
1, 15.24, 25, 2, 1, 1), Correct.Outcome = c("N", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N"), Reason = c("over 50", NA, NA, "over 50", "over 50", 
NA, NA, "cumulative amount over 50", "over 50", NA, NA, "cumulative amount over 50", 
"cumulative amount over 50", "cumulative amount over 50", "cumulative clicks over 5 and cumulative amount over 50", 
"Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code:

```
 results=testdat%>% group_by(ID)%>%arrange(date)%>%
  mutate(cum.clicks=cumsum(ifelse(click.amount<=50 & Group=="A",clicks,0)),
         cum.clickamount=cumsum(ifelse(click.amount<=50 & Group=="A",click.amount,0)))%>%
  mutate(Outcome=ifelse(click.amount<=50 & Group=="A" & cum.clicks<=5 & cum.clickamount<=50,"Y","N" ))%>%
  select(Outcome,Correct.Outcome,Reason,everything())%>%
  arrange(ID,date)%>%
  mutate(check=ifelse(Outcome !=Correct.Outcome,1,0))%>% ungroup()%>%
  summarize(prop50=mean(Outcome=="Y"),amount50=sum(click.amount[Outcome=="Y"]))
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A full sample output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're doing, but turning dplyr into function can be done using `sapply`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
testdata <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                       date = c(1550245200, 1550245211, 1550245411, 1552566300,
                                1552566350, 1552567300, 1552567400,
                                1552567500, 1552568600, 1552568600, 1552568601,
                                1552568691, 1552568691, 1552568891, 1552568899,
                                1552568601, 1552568691, 1552568691, 1552568891,
                                1552568899),
                       ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7,
                              8),
                       Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                 "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                 "B"),
                       clicks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                  1),
                       click.amount = c(60, 4.89, 12.84, 70, 52, 10, 33, 80, 54, 11.89, 15.24,
                                        25, 2, 1, 1, 15.24, 25, 2, 1, 1),
                       Correct.Outcome = c("N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y",
                                           "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N",
                                           "N"),
                       Reason = c("over 50", NA, NA, "over 50", "over 50", NA, NA,
                                  "cumulative amount over 50", "over 50", NA,
                                  NA, "cumulative amount over 50",
                                  "cumulative amount over 50", "cumulative amount over 50",
                                  "cumulative clicks over 5 and cumulative amount over 50", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B",
                                  "Group B", "Group B"))
results <- sapply(X = 20:200,
                  FUN = function(t) {
                    testdata %>%
                      group_by(ID) %>%
                      arrange(date) %>%
                      mutate(cum.clicks = cumsum(x = ifelse(test = ((click.amount <= t) & (Group == "A")),
                                                            yes = clicks,
                                                            no = 0)),
                             cum.clickamount = cumsum(x = ifelse(test = ((click.amount <= t) & (Group=="A")),
                                                                 yes = click.amount,
                                                                 no = 0))) %>%
                      mutate(Outcome = ifelse(test = ((click.amount <= t) & (Group == "A") & (cum.clicks <= 5) & (cum.clickamount <= t)),
                                              yes = "Y",
                                              no = "N" )) %>%
                      select(Outcome, Correct.Outcome, Reason, everything()) %>%
                      arrange(ID, date) %>%
                      mutate(check = ifelse(test = (Outcome !=Correct.Outcome),
                                            yes = 1,
                                            no = 0)) %>%
                      ungroup()%>%
                      summarize(proportion = mean(Outcome == "Y"),
                                amount = sum(click.amount[Outcome=="Y"]))
                  })
results
#>            [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]
#> proportion 0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.25  0.25 
#> amount     39.62 39.62 39.62 39.62 39.62 39.62 39.62 39.62 54.86 54.86
#>            [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#> proportion 0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25 
#> amount     54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86 54.86
#>            [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30]
#> proportion 0.25  0.25  0.25  0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3  
#> amount     54.86 54.86 54.86 87.86 87.86 87.86 87.86 87.86 87.86 87.86
#>            [,31] [,32] [,33]  [,34]  [,35]  [,36]  [,37]  [,38]  [,39] 
#> proportion 0.3   0.3   0.35   0.4    0.4    0.45   0.5    0.5    0.5   
#> amount     87.86 87.86 139.86 164.86 164.86 166.86 167.86 167.86 167.86
#>            [,40]  [,41]  [,42]  [,43]  [,44]  [,45]  [,46]  [,47]  [,48] 
#> proportion 0.5    0.45   0.45   0.45   0.45   0.45   0.5    0.5    0.5   
#> amount     167.86 210.13 210.13 210.13 210.13 210.13 215.02 215.02 215.02
#>            [,49]  [,50]  [,51]  [,52]  [,53]  [,54]  [,55]  [,56]  [,57] 
#> proportion 0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5   
#> amount     215.02 215.02 233.02 233.02 233.02 233.02 233.02 233.02 233.02
#>            [,58]  [,59]  [,60]  [,61]  [,62]  [,63]  [,64]  [,65]  [,66] 
#> proportion 0.5    0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55  
#> amount     233.02 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86
#>            [,67]  [,68]  [,69]  [,70]  [,71]  [,72]  [,73]  [,74]  [,75] 
#> proportion 0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55  
#> amount     245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86
#>            [,76]  [,77]  [,78]  [,79]  [,80]  [,81]  [,82]  [,83]  [,84] 
#> proportion 0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55  
#> amount     245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86
#>            [,85]  [,86]  [,87]  [,88]  [,89]  [,90]  [,91]  [,92]  [,93] 
#> proportion 0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55  
#> amount     245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86
#>            [,94]  [,95]  [,96]  [,97]  [,98]  [,99]  [,100] [,101] [,102]
#> proportion 0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55   0.55  
#> amount     245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86 245.86
#>            [,103] [,104] [,105] [,106] [,107] [,108] [,109] [,110] [,111]
#> proportion 0.6    0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     297.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,112] [,113] [,114] [,115] [,116] [,117] [,118] [,119] [,120]
#> proportion 0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,121] [,122] [,123] [,124] [,125] [,126] [,127] [,128] [,129]
#> proportion 0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,130] [,131] [,132] [,133] [,134] [,135] [,136] [,137] [,138]
#> proportion 0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,139] [,140] [,141] [,142] [,143] [,144] [,145] [,146] [,147]
#> proportion 0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,148] [,149] [,150] [,151] [,152] [,153] [,154] [,155] [,156]
#> proportion 0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65   0.65  
#> amount     377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86 377.86
#>            [,157] [,158] [,159] [,160] [,161] [,162] [,163] [,164] [,165]
#> proportion 0.65   0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7   
#> amount     377.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86
#>            [,166] [,167] [,168] [,169] [,170] [,171] [,172] [,173] [,174]
#> proportion 0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7   
#> amount     431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86
#>            [,175] [,176] [,177] [,178] [,179] [,180] [,181]
#> proportion 0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7    0.7   
#> amount     431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86 431.86
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: this does exactly what I want except when I unlist the results.  How would I manipulate  the results to get two columns for each t?

Comment: @alleyway `results` is a matrix. Its 1st column correspond to `20`, 2nd to `21`, etc. So for `t`, you'll e interested in the `t-19`th column. You can get that by `results[,t-19]`. It'll have 2 rows and 1 column. So you can use `t()` to get 2 columns.

Comment: Perfect, `df=as.data.frame(t(results))`. Thanks for the quick and clean response!